# Change line width (thickness) sjPlot sjp.int R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, sjplot

I would like to change the width of the lines (thicker lines) in an sjp.int plot. I tried all help arguments, but somehow could not find it.

Example code:

```
require(ggplot2) 
require(sjPlot) 
head(diamonds) 
test<-lm(price ~ carat*depth, data=diamonds)
sjp.int(test, type = "eff")
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: [Here](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/custplot/) is an overview of things you *can* change, but line size doesn't seem to among them.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change line size for `sjp.int` currently, so you have to modify the returned plot object(s), which are in the return value `plot.list`. Then you can overwrite `geom_line()`.

```
dummy <- sjp.int(test, type = "eff")
dummy$plot.list[[1]] + geom_line(size = 3)
```

[image]

I've added a `geom.size` argument to `sjp.int`, see [GitHub](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel).